# Stream audio rather than download

Tags: html, http, audio, stream

I can't find any definitive answer on this.

Is it possible to use a continuous MP3 (or other) stream that is delivered just ahead of time over http as a `src` for the html [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) tag. Think radio. My experiments in this area seem to indicate that audio that has already been played stacks up in memory, potentially making a continuous stream an infinite memory hog.

It seems that delivering a content-length is out, so will using a chunked encoding, or [http/0.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) (which has no indication of content length) make a difference? Are there any specs on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a streaming Server for this. With plain http/1.0 i see no way. Maybe you can use http/1.1 Content-Range and some javascript. to extend your stream.

Comment: I'm writing a streaming server ;) How would a streaming server deliver content to the page? Something other than `<audio>`?

Comment: <video> with a mp3-stream is more likely to work. You can find some details on this discussion on http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?14071-Streaming-to-HTML5-audio-tag